# Socket not returning NULL or \n for ReadLine()

Tags: javascript, sockets, bufferedreader, readline

I've read up several articles and questions related to the readLine() hanging. I'm not sure if I can manually add a NULL at the end of the response from the server side (it's remote location). As far as I can tell, I probably can't control it.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Response>
 <Reply Status="OK" />
 <Data attr="..." />    <-- BufferedReader hangs after this is printed. 
 </Response>    <--- I'm assuming this has no "\n" or "null" so it keeps waiting 
                     till the socket closes
```

What can I do to fix this? I don't exactly need the last line but I don't want my code to keep having exceptions. I'm using Javascript and here is a portion of my code.

```
 if (socketForXML && socketForXML.isConnected()){
    socketForXML.setSoTimeout(60000);
    var command = new Packages.java.lang.String( theCommand );

    var os = socketForXML.getOutputStream();
    os.write( command.getBytes("UTF-8") );
    os.flush();
    log.info("sendXMLCommand - sent command : " + command);

    //RECEIVE RESPONSE FROM SERVER - in STRING format
    var inStream = socketForXML.getInputStream();
    var reader = new Packages.java.io.InputStreamReader(inStream, "UTF-8");
    var buffer = new Packages.java.io.BufferedReader( reader );
    while( ( line = buffer.readLine() ) != null ) {
        log.debug(line);
    }
    socketForXML.close();
```

}

I've also tried using buffer.read() and it'll get me all the ASCII numbers for the /Response tag but after that last > it will hang as well. I tried doing a check with try catch but it will still wait until socket closes and nothing is ever returned :(.

```
try{
    if (buffer.read() < 0 ){
      log.error("END OF FILE.");
    }
catch(e) {
    log.error("did not work.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the response DID have a null at the end.

The problem was that the inputStream was not shut down properly. The Socket class has two methods called:

[isInputShutdown()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isInputShutdown%28%29) <- to check if the input stream is shut down

[inputShutdown()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#shutdownInput%28%29) <-- to shut the input stream, leaving the socket still open

I'm not entirely clear as to why it would botch the buffer from reading and causing it to hang but it's possible that it kept trying to stream and the buffer was full - when there's nothing left to receive from the input stream.

```
while( ( line = buffer.readLine() ) != null ) {
    log.debug(line);
    if ( !inStream.isInputShutdown() ){
           inStream.shutdownInput();
    }
}
```

Comment: In other words you only want to read one line from the server? In that case just get rid of the loop. You don't need to shut anything down. Otherwise this answer doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @World: this is a self-answer. It doesn't look bad enough to delete.

Answer (score 0):

readLine() *never* returns \n, and it hangs if there isn't a line to read. The way to accomplish what you're looking for isn't to 'add a NULL' at the server or shutdown the input at the client, it is to *close the socket* at the server. *That* will cause readLine() to return null. Per your own answer it is difficult to see why you have a loop if all you want is one line.